# Automapper Custom Map use "Include" to get children count

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, automapper

I have an asp net core 2.1 project. 
The db context is made with EF.
This is my db model for SecGroups and SecGroupRights:

```
public partial class SecGroups
{
    public SecGroups()
    {
        SecGroupRights = new HashSet<SecGroupRights>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? IsReference { get; set; }
    public long? Provider { get; set; }
    public long? Class { get; set; }

    public SecGroups IdNavigation { get; set; }
    public SecGroups InverseIdNavigation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SecGroupRights> SecGroupRights { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class SecGroupRights
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    public long RightId { get; set; }

    public SecGroups Group { get; set; }
    public SecRights Right { get; set; }
}
```

This is just a simple one to many relationship between SecGroups and SecGroupRights.

If I get SecGroups thru the `_context`, for instance like `var grDB=_context.SecGroups.FirstOrDefault();` I always have `grDB.SecGroupRights` null (even if it has children)

I found out that I have to get it using "Include" in order to get the children:

```
var grDB = await _context.SecGroups.Include(a => a.SecGroupRights)
.Where(a => a.Id == myID)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This works very well and I can access to the SecGroupRights data and eventually get their count.

Now the next thing is to make a custom AutoMapper mapping from `SecGroups` to this one:

```
public class GroupsDto
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? Provider { get; set; }
    public long? Rights { get; set; }
}
```

So in the Rights field I just want the count of the children. In my above scenario that would be:

```
grDB.SecGroupRights.Count();
```

I try to do a mapping like so:

```
        CreateMap<SecGroups, GroupsDto>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(d => d.Rights, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SecGroupRights.Count()));
```

Unfortunately, the problem is that while mapping the SecGroupRights object comes empty and I always get 0 count.

So I tried injecting the _context in my Mapping helper and ended up with this:

```
        CreateMap<SecGroups, GroupsDto>(MemberList.Source)
        .ForMember(d => d.Rights, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (
            _context.SecGroupRights.Where(a => a.GroupId==src.Id).Count()

        )));
```

But it seems that I get no error and also no count so I assume that the mapper has no access to the `_context`.

Is there any way I can get this count in my mapper? Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

**---------------------------------**
**Edit:**

Mapping did not work because when I was using the mapper I did not have SecGroupRights in the source.

So for reference the good mapping is:

```
CreateMap<SecGroups, GroupsDto>(MemberList.Source)
.ForMember(d => d.Rights, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SecGroupRights.Count()));
```

And I called it so:

```
var res= _context.SecGroups.Include(a => a.SecGroupRights).ToList();
var mapped = _mapper.Map<List<SecGroups>, List<GroupsDto>>(res);
```

Comment: Try checking list SecGroupRights in MemberList.Source contain the data before creating a map.

Comment: Indeed my bad was that I did not include SecGroupRights in the source of the object to be mapped!

Comment: Well played, my friend :))

Comment: This is what happens  when you use a lot of new technologies at once and need to get stuff done in the meantime. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping did not work because when I was using the mapper I did not have SecGroupRights in the source.

So for reference the good mapping is:

```
CreateMap<SecGroups, GroupsDto>(MemberList.Source)
.ForMember(d => d.Rights, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SecGroupRights.Count()));
```

And I called it so:

```
var res= _context.SecGroups.Include(a => a.SecGroupRights).ToList();
var mapped = _mapper.Map<List<SecGroups>, List<GroupsDto>>(res);
```